# Liquibase file path in Spring Configuration file

Tags: java, spring, maven-3, liquibase

I have a Spring Configuration java file in my project (i.e. with `@Configuration` annotation). Now I'm creating a bean of `SpringLiquibase` in this class. The main file of changelogs i.e. `db.changelog.xml` file is in resources folder. So directly it's accessible from `resources` folder if I use `springLiquibaseObj.setChangeLog("classpath:db.changelog.xml");` method. But when I try to access other xml files from `db.changelog.xml` file with 
 `<include file="src/main/config/db/db.changelog-main.xml" />` I get error that folder and file is not found.

Here, I want to keep `db.changelog.xml` file in `resources` folder and all other new changelog files in `config` folder which should be at same level as `resources`. The reason for this is, in `resources` folder, packages are there so folder structure `config/1.0.0` is considered as `config/1/0/0` which I don't want.

Is there any way to achieve this structure (shown below) with the current set up in my project?

> - config
>
>   - 1.0.0
>
>     - db.changelog.201412120101.xml
>   - 1.1.0
>   - 2.0.0
> - resources
>
>   - db.changelog.xml

or

> - config
>
>   - 1.0.0
>
>     - db.changelog.201412120101.xml
>   - 1.1.0
>   - 2.0.0
>   - db.changelog.xml
> - resources

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution for this. Before this, I had copied the folder `src/main/config` into `src/main/resouces` in netbeans so it took that folder as package. So the folder name - `config/db/1.0.0` got changed to `config/db/1/0/0`, but when I created new folder in `resources` folder, it worked and all the files in folder `1.0.0` are accessible correctly. Now, my folder structure is like this:

> - resources
>
>   - config
>
>     - db
>
>       - 1.0.0
>
>         - db.changelog.201412120101.xml
>       - 1.1.0
>       - 2.0.0
>   - db.changelog.xml

I can access `db.changelog.xml` file from my Spring class as,
`springLiquibaseObj.setChangeLog("classpath:db.changelog.xml");` and other changelog files from `db.changelog.xml` file as, 
`<include file="classpath:config/db/1.0.0/db.changelog-201412120101.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="false" />`.

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase uses the application classpath, so as long as config is in your classpath you should be able to load them as well.

They would have a path relative to config, so something like "src="1.0.0/db.changelog.201312120101.xml" in your example.

If config isn't in the classpath, you can use the relativeToChangeLog="true" attribute with a src="../../config/1.0.0/db.changelog.201412120101.xml" but having config directly accessible by liquibase is the cleaner option.

Comment: config folder is not in resources as I have to keep it outside because of naming issues. You can see the hierarchy above in my question, I have that and I want `config` folder to be accessible from Spring Configuration file and `db.changelog.xml`. I have tried giving these kind of paths, also this `relativeToChangeLog` attribute it's not working.

Comment: It should be fine to have config outside of resources, it is just a matter of configuring spring. Liquibase uses spring's configured ResourceLoader to find the changelog files. Are you able to configure that to look in config along with resources?